# How to make svg elements so that it always take full width and height of it's parent?

Tags: html, css, xml, svg, frontend

Suppose this is the code I've

```
    <div class="container pt-120 pb-120">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div>
            <div class="parent">
              <h1>Hello World</h1>
              <h2>Hello World</h2>
              <div class="mt-60">
                <a href="#">View More</a>
              </div>
              <div class="mt-80">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque at adipisci cumque quam minima tenetur?
                  Assumenda ipsam provident eos voluptatum temporibus. Blanditiis cum corrupti ratione sequi, unde fugiat
                  error esse?</p>
              </div>
              <div class="svg-wrapper>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-2 -2 436 258" fill="none">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"
              d="M245.222 3.45063C241.909 1.20209 237.996 0 233.992 0H20C8.95431 0 0 8.95431 0 20V234C0 245.046 8.95431 254 20 254H412C423.046 254 432 245.046 432 234V44C432 32.9543 423.046 24 412 24H281.65C277.645 24 273.733 22.7979 270.42 20.5494L245.222 3.45063Z" />
          </svg>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I want to use the .svg-wrapper as a background to my .parent class. But the problem is if i add more content to the parent then the svg not scaling correctly. I want no matter what's the parent size, the svg'll always take the full width and height of it's parent. Also when I set stroke on it, sometimes it's getting cut off. Can't figuring out how to do this properly.

I'm trying to achieve this with the svg. No matter what is the parent size, but Svg'll take the full width and height also. Also the stroke'll be work perfectly without cutting any edge of it. Like the css box-sizing:border-box; does. Please review this image

[image]

I'm experimenting too much time to achieve this, but I can't.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you don't want to preserve the aspect ratio of the viewBox then set preserveAspectRatio="none"

Comment: Yes. This is what I'm looking for. Many many thanks. Can You please help me to get the control of the stroke. Because strokes are getting cut off. Here is the current code ` <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" rx="10" ry="10" height="100%" fill="red" stroke="white" stroke-width="4px" />
                </svg>`

Comment: If you've another question, best ask it separately.